# WP_Query doesn't work when url parameter is added

Tags: wp-query

I have this problem which has got me boggled. For some strange reason, WP_Query doesn't return results when a url parameter is present in the url. That is
when open the url:

`https://xxxxxxx.com`

The query runs fine, however:
when I open the url:

`https://xxxxxx.com?lang=de`

No data is returned. What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a plain white screen? If so, have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: It's seems to be related to the WPML plugin, though I still haven't found a fix yet